# PBR: Why conductors have tinted specular?

Tags: optics, lenses, lightning

So, as I know when light beam falls on some surface it reflect (specular) and refract (diffuse).

Refracted part will interact with material's molecules and it can lose all energy or fly back out of the material - this will be diffuse lighting (color of the material). Since conductors have free electrons and light beam is electromagnetic wave - conductors don't have a diffuse part.

Reflected part. For dielectrics it works like: beam does not interact with the material, it will just mirrored from it. I mean for example if we took ideally red ball (1, 0, 0) and blue light source (0, 0, 1) then we will see only blue specular part. So dielectric's specular color equal to light source color.

But who can explain me in simple way why conductor's specular is colored? I know that this is described by the Fresnel equations, but I don’t understand them :(

Comment: These may help - [Green light on red article](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191585/37364), [If we repeatedly divide a colorful solid in half, at what point will the color disappear?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/634760/37364)

Comment: thank you, so electrons will absorb the beam and then emit some light :d

Comment: The electrons absorb light at some frequencies, period. At others, there are two more or less equivalent ways the think about it. They absorb and re-emit light. Or they reflect light.